# In notepad++, is it possible to freeze the active line

Tags: notepad++, freeze

Is it possible to freeze the active line in the text window, regardless of which line of code is actually displayed?

I want to be able to view code above and below my active line and stay horizontally centered as I enter text.

I've checked all options within Notepad++, including plugins and searching the web with little success. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm long with N++ but I don't know such a feature in N++ or plugins.

The closest thing you can get is to manually scroll the viewport by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

At the moment I don't know any text editor with such a feature.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the Ctrl Up and Down. In the nineties, I used to use a paid editor named UltraEdit which I believe had that capability, though I could be wrong. I just know that I used to use it. I could toggle the feature on and off, and the selected line would freeze, while the text would flow up or down . When I code or write, I like to see the big picture of what I have written so that I don't get lost in the details (can't see the forest among the trees).

Comment: @RichVerry – [UtraEdit is still available](http://www.ultraedit.com/) so you can check desired functionality on a trial version and potentially you can purchase it.